# change position of category attribute in General information in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

[image: How to change attribute position in category up or down as per requirement?]
How to change attribute position in category up or down as per requirement?

Comment: short description is your custom attribute?

Comment: Yes, I wants to change position of short description. It comes before Description attribute.

Comment: If `short_description` is your custom attribute then you can change its position be defining its sort order

Comment: could you show the code which you have to create the short description attribute

Comment: $this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'short_description', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'label'         => 'Short Description',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'   => 'text',
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => true,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'is_visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'default'       => ''
));

Comment: Can we done this through mysql4-install-1.0.0 file?

Comment: There is a little bit better answer on a question asked a year after this one. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92938/283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an ugly way of doing it but I have nothing else.

The attribute position in the attribute groups is kept in the `eav_entity_attribute` table.
First you need to identify the id of your attribute `short_description`.

Here is the query for that.

```
SELECT 
    attribute_id, attribute_code
FROM 
    eav_attribute 
WHERE
    attribute_code = 'short_description' AND
    entity_type_id = (SELECT 
                          entity_type_id
                      FROM
                          eav_entity_type
                      WHERE 
                          entity_type_code = 'catalog_category'
                     )
```

Let's say the attribute id you get is `100`.

Then you need to get the attributes id of the attribute that should be above your attribute and below it.

Use the same query above but change the attribute code from `short_description` to `is_anchor` and `description`.

Let's say you got the values 10 for `is_anchor` and 15 for `description`.

Then see their position in the attribute sets.

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_entity_attribute` where `attribute_id` in (10, 15, 100);
```

Look at the `sort_order` field.
Let's say you have something like this:

```
attribute_id|sort_order
10          | 40            //is_anchor attribute
15          | 50            //description attribute
100         | 120           //shot_description attribute
```

All you need now is to update the sort_order for the short_description attribute to be between the values for is_anchor and description.
In the example above you will need `45`

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_attribute` set `sort_order` = 45 where `attribute_id` = 100
```

Comment: @ParagDave. Most probably it can be done through an install script, but I have no idea how. That's why I wrote this ugly solution.

Comment: Marius, in the install script, specify `'sort_order' => 45,`

Answer (score 1):

The backend category page is rendered from files in:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category    
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category
```

But it's complex and there's also a lot of javascript in there.

Comment: It is right for product attribute, but i wants to change the order of category attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via an update script

```
$installer->run("
    update {$installer->getTable('eav_entity_attribute')} set `sort_order`=1 where `attribute_id`=(select `attribute_id` from {$installer->getTable('eav_attribute')} where `attribute_code`='short_description');
");
```

If the sort order is not correct, try setting the sort_order value to 0 or as a last resort, change the sort_order values of other attributes as well.

Answer (score -4):

Some things can be solved without going into the code :)

Just:
1. Go into your Catalog/attribute/manage attribute sets/ your attributeset.
2. Drag and drop the attribute where you want it
3. Save your attribute set

[image]

Comment: The question was related to category fields in the admin area, not product attributes.